# file_get_contents not working for remote files

Tags: php

file_get_contents not working in hostgator but working fine in localhost

thanks in advance.

```
$query = file_get_contents('http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/test.php');
print_r($query);
echo $query;
```

i need to get data from above url .

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(http://xxxx/servers/read.php): failed to open stream: Connection refused in /home2/xxxxxxxxx.co.in/secure_me/webservices/getServerLists.php on line 13

Comment: This is the error i am getting

Comment: Well, the remote server is refusing the connection then. Why that is is up to anyone's guess here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that some hosts disable `allow_url_fopen` in the `php.ini` file. Maybe hostgator disabled it. Read more [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen).

You can use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php) for this problem.

Comment: allow_url_fopen  this is enabled

Comment: i have checked enabled or desabled using phpinfo(). option is enabled

Comment: @RamalingamRamasamy do you get an error too if you use curl?

Comment: No simply display empty page

Comment: @RamalingamRamasamy Can you show your cURL code too?

Comment: can u share exact curl code with content-type : application/json

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);  
       $curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://xxxxxxxxxxx/test.php');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
print_r($query);
curl_close($curl_handle);

Comment: what happen...?